# Kill query execution as another different user using Execute AS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to kill my own time consuming query execution but it is saying I cannot kill my own process as Microsoft stated in the remarks section:

> Remarks 
>   KILL is commonly used to end a process that is blocking other
>   important processes with locks. KILL can also be used to stop a
>   process that is executing a query that is using necessary system
>   resources. System processes and processes running an extended stored
>   procedure can't be ended.
>
> Use KILL carefully, especially when critical processes are running.
>   You can't kill your own process.

I use below T-SQL commands:

```
EXECUTE sp_who2 'active'
Kill <SPID VALUE>
```

Anyway I can kill my own process If I login into SQL Server as another user by opening a new session and typing above two commands.

Now I would like to do the same without the need to open a new session with another user. So from my opened session, I am performing below T-SQL commands:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';
EXECUTE sp_who2 'active'
KILL <SPID VALUE>
REVERT;
```

But they are not working. Why?

Comment: Right, you can't kill it in your own process because your current process is busy with the original query. Are you trying to kill it from the same query window? Just open a new query window and kill the process that is holding you up

Comment: You did not get the SPID for the time consuming query. You got the SPID for the window where you tried the KILL command. Look at the sp_who2 results again.